# How does python function return statement work?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to `python` but I have experience with other languages like `nodejs, java` etc. I have a function in `python` defined like:

```
from flask import abort
def delete_contact(contact_id, api_key=None):  # noqa: E501

    print('delete contact ', contact_id)
    session = Session()
    try:
        query = session.query(DBContact).filter(DBContact.id == contact_id)
        print('delete count:', query.count())
        if query.count() == 0:
            print('return 404')
            return abort(404, 'Not find record')
        contact = query.one()
        session.delete(contact)
        session.commit()
        return 'success'
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        session.close()
    print('xxxxx')
    return abort(400, 'failed to delete contact ' + contact_id)
```

When execution this code I can see the output includes both `return 404` and `xxxxx`. I don't understand why `xxxxx` get printed if the function returns in `return abort(404, 'Not find record')` already. In other language like `java, javascript`, if a function returns a value, the rest code should not execute except `finally` block. But the `print('xxxxx')` is outside `finally` block. Why is it executed?

Comment: *"When execution this code"* - How are you executing the code? I couldn't reproduce this

Comment: If `abort(404, 'Not find record')` raises an exception then the rest of the function will continue as the except block just prints the exception. In this case you would get 'return 404' followed by the exception being printed followed by 'xxxxx'

Comment: @IainShelvington The code doesn't just _call_ `abort()`, it _returns_ it.  Would the try/except still catch it in that case?

Comment: Yes, any exceptions raised by the `abort` function will be be "caught" by the catch-all exception statement in your code even though it is part of a return statement

Comment: It returns the value of calling `abort()`; if `abort()` raises an exception during its execution, the `return` won't be reached.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `abort` is from `flash` which raise an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abort(404, 'Not find record')` raises a `HTTPException`, which is caught by your `except` block.

Therefore the `return` part of the `return abort(404, 'Not find record')` statement is never reached and instead of returning python will execute the `except` block followed by the `finally` block and then the statements after the `try-except-finally` statement.

The function then doesn't return either, because the line

```
return abort(400, 'failed to delete contact ' + contact_id)
```

raises another `HTTPException`, which will be propagated through the call stack.

The `return`s don't do anything.

If you want to propagate the `HTTPException`, but not other exceptions, you could do something like:

```
try:
    ...
except HTTPException:
    raise
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    ...
...
```

This will raise the `HTTPException`s thrown by `abort`, but handle all other exceptions in the second `except` block, continuing the function afterwards.

Comment: what your suggestion to fix this? Do I have to add a `abort(error)` inside the `except` block?